# Run prebuild step with Xcode's new build system

Tags: xcode, xcode10

In Xcode I had a prebuild step that got executed before the compilation of every module which generated some code. In Xcode 10 I want to use the new build system, but the files must be present before. My Xcode 9 steps looked like this:

```
1. generated files for foo
2. build foo.a
3. generated files for bar
4. build bar.dylib
```

Is there a way to generate all of the files at once (and not per project) so Xcode's new build system can use the generated files? Here is what I need:

```
1. generated files for foo
2. generated files for bar
3. build foo.a
4. build bar.dylib
```

Any ideas? Thanks so much!